# Attributi attribuiti agli animali in italiano

Tags: list

Buongiorno,

Dove posso trovare una lista di attributi associati con animali nella lingua italiana? Per esempio:

- pecora: copiona
- asini: ignorante
- volpe: furba
- gufo: saggio
- maiale: sessualmente rozzo (?)

Dove posso trovare l'intera lista?

Grazie.

Comment: Pecora "copiona"? :) Piuttosto, direi codarda o remissiva.

Comment: Forse qui: https://www.mitiemisteri.it/simbologia-significato-degli-animali

Comment: Ho trovato queste due pagine:
http://community.middlebury.edu/~aokal/exploration-metaforeanimali.htm
http://www.anima-morte-eternita.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=258:gli-animali-nelle-metafore&catid=65:animali-natura&Itemid=107

Comment: “Copione” significa che copia idee altrui, e specialmente i compiti degli altri a scuola. Intendevi forse qualcosa come “gregaria”? D'altro canto non è sorprendente, visto che “gregario” ha la stessa origine di “gregge”...